# ide does not find packages shim and proto packages in $GOPATH

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, goland

I have been setting up a small Hyperledger fabric application. It is already running and I can add delete and change users.

But until now I have been using nano to code until now.

I want to change to a proper ide (goland) for the sake of autocompletion and so on.

The problem is: On my local machine it can not find the packages

```
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
```

The gopath is set up correctly but the two packages are not in the folders. I.e also a local go build does not work.

The packages are present on the CLI though.

How can I install the dependencies so that I also have them on my local machine? And is this even desired and if so why not?

ps: I have already tried 
`go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim`
the resulting error is:

`package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
    /home/funuser/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOPATH)`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, the shim and protos were moved to stand-alone repositories several months ago, you need to do a `go get` on `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim` and `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go` and change your import references to these new repos:

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"
   pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer"
)
```

Comment: Nice :) This are the wanted packages and got them. One problem I encounter though is that the path that works on the CLI (the docker container) has the packages inside the fabric. i.e. every time I deploy I would have to change the path. 
e.g. from "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" to "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/core/chaincode/shim"
Is there a solution to the different imports on different machines or can I alter the name of the path so that I don't have to change it every deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `go get` only imports go code files.  Other assets like the raw proto files are excluded. An option is to check-out the git repo in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric`

Comment: I have alreadry cloned the hyperledger/fabric repo. Unfortunately it seems that github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim is not present. As can be seen in the github repository under: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/core/chaincode

Might it be that I have to build?

Comment: My answer was predominantly related to the missing proto files. From what I can remember the shim relates to your own code.  I haven’t looked at the makefile, but building may create a sample application and it’s shim.

Comment: Shim is a standard library for hyperledger what I conceive. Do you know if I can generate the protofile?

Comment: No, your chai code uses a shim to interact with the hyper-ledger APIs

Comment: What do you mean by chai code? I will talk to my professor if he has an idea and will update this post once i found a solution. Thank you for your generouse help though :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me https://www.programmersought.com/article/17446289383/
additional any one using this thread now need to update the pkgs to
"github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"
pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer"